# DrawerNavigator: Change Text Color

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

On `react-navigation`'s `DrawerNavigator`, is there a way to change the text color and background color for the item?

By default, the color scheme looks like the following:
[image: react-navigation color]

Which is initialized by the following:

```
export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    dOne: {
      screen: Screen1,
    },
    dTwo: {
      screen: Screen2,
    }
  }
);
```

Setting the `color` property within the screen's `contentOptions`'s `style` does not appear to have an effect.

Should I extend new components for each row (labeled "Primary", "Secondary", etc. right now)? or is there an easier way to stylize the existing implementation of the rows?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of `style` you need to use `labelStyle` inside contentOptions. Like this:

```
contentOptions: {
  labelStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'SomeFont',
    color: 'white',
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a place in the documentation that specifies this?

Comment: You can dig into the source code. https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/5e075e1c31d5e6192f2532a815b1737fa27ed65b/src/views/Drawer/DrawerNavigatorItems.js

Answer (score 19):

A google search landed me here but the answer could not resolve my issue: I wanted to change the text color but have it switch between different colors depending on whether active and or inactive. Chnangin the colorin labelstyle effectively ensured the labels are the same color irrespective of the state. So I used the tint colors in content options of the drawer.

```
    export const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator(
  {... /drawer items}
 ,
  {
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.primary,
      activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
      inactiveTintColor: 'black',
      inactiveBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        marginLeft: 10,
      },
    },
    drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.7,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  }
);
```

This way I can alternate colors depending on whether a drawer item is active or not using the `activeTintColor and inactiveTintColor` options.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is using Navigation V5 you will have to follow the below method and do that when initializing the drawer navigator

```
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'red',
          activeBackgroundColor: 'grey',
          inactiveTintColor: 'blue',
          inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
          labelStyle:{
            marginLeft:5
          }
        }}>
  </Drawer.Navigator>
```

You can refer the docs for more props
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontentoptions

Comment: Color red should be in small caps `activeTintColor: 'red',`

Comment: @cmcodes updated it, thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: can we change the drawer font family here? @GuruparanGiritharan

Answer (score 1):

You can render your custom `label`:

```
import { DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

// ...

<DrawerItem label={() => <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>White text</Text>} />;
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent