# Can't seem to change styles on a React-Navigation DrawerNavigation ( Text Color )

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am building a react native application with expo and I am using the following drawer component

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/

I am able to style the background color inline, but using `labelStyle :{ color: 'white' }` and other stylings do not change the appearance of the drawer.

Here is what I have so far...

```
 <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="LoL" drawerStyle={{
 backgroundColor: 'orange'}} >
```

Why is the background changing but no other sytles seem to work?

I also found that some people pass in props to their `const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();` , but when I try to do the same thing I get an error that `createDrawerNavigator() does not take in any props`

Exmaple of someone doing: [DrawerNavigator: Change Text Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930525/drawernavigator-change-text-color)

Is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass the colors as drawerContentOptions

For example you can set the activeTintColor like below

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerContentOptions={{activeTintColor:'red'}}>
```

You can refer the docs here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontentoptions

Comment: Okay I see. The inline styles I am giving are only effecting the drawer navigator parent so I must use the options to access any content inside. Thank you. I did attempt to use the activeTintColors but it didn't do anything. Thanks for the help.