# How do I change the text color and highlighted color in the react native drawer navigation

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I was able to change the background color but I cannot change the text and highlighted color. how can i do I've attached my codes and screenshot.

[image]

```js
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator 
      drawerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#b7657b',
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Anasayfa" component={Home} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Kullanım" component={dnm} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Hakkımızda" component={info} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="hsc" component={hsc} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64650643/1435722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'red',
          activeBackgroundColor: 'grey',
          inactiveTintColor: 'blue',
          inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
          labelStyle:{
            fontSize: 15,
            marginLeft:5
          }
        }}>
</Drawer.Navigator>
```